# How prevent global shift-containing hotkey from interfering with SendKeys.Send() in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, sendkeys

### Summary

How do you prevent the shift-key, which is part of a global hotkey, from interfering when sending text to the active window in Windows, by calling System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("abc") from another process when a shift-containing-global-hotkey is activated?

### The problem

The window which is active when the hotkey is activated misinterpret the text sent to since the shift-key, which is part of the hotkey, is still pressed while it receives and process the the text sent to it. It is humanly impossible to release the shift-key fast enough so it is still not pressed when the text is received.
**It is not possible to change the hotkey to not contain shift**, and even if were possible, the ctrl-key would interfere with the processing in a similar way.
The sending application is run as a normal user without admin privileges, and UAC is enabled.

- There is a background application running in windows. It is a normal .NET C# WinForm application, started by the user and running without a visible GUI.
- The background application has registered a global hotkey, that is, a hotkey that can be pressed anywhere in Windows, no matter which application is currently active.
- The hotkey is: `<shift>+F9`  (`RegisterHotKey(hWnd, hotkeyId, 4/*MOD_SHIFT*/, 120 /*Keys.F9*/`);
- When the hotkey is activated, the background application calls `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("abc")`
- The active window receives the text "abc", but since the shift-key from the hotkey is still pressed, the result end up as "ABC".

### The question

What are the possible ways to make sure the text sent end up the same after the receiving window get, process and interpret it?
That is, when sending "abc" to a running instance of notepad.exe by pressing `<shift>+F9`, the text showing up in notepad should be "abc" and not "ABC".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell,

1. Check the Shift modifier status, and only send your keys after you verify that it is not pressed
2. Don't use SendKeys

I think that #1 is pretty self explanatory, but keep in mind that even if you verify that Shift is not pressed before you start sending keys, Its possible that the user can still press Shift or another modifier while you are sending keys, or even worse its possible for the active window to lose focus and stop it completely. If you're designing a program that simply inserts user-defined text after a hotkey press and the user is expecting it, then this is not a big deal and is the appropriate way to to this.

You have a few options for #2, I'd suggest looking into using [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [An apropriate message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468861%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (WM_CHAR, WM_SETTEXT, WM_KEYDOWN, or etc) to send a message directly to the window in question.

After everything is said, its important to realise that this is a really uncertain process. You can never guarantee that simulating keyboard inputs or sending key messages will register as you would like them to and it may largely depend on the application your sending messages to (esp in the case of SendMessage).